# How to fix Uncaught Error: Expected a value of type 'LIElement', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: dart

I try to populate a UListElement from JSon in Dart and I get this error message "Uncaught Error: Expected a value of type 'LIElement', but got one of type '_JsonMap'". How can I fix it?

I saw similar examples but nothing works.

My code is
//*******
  List jsonBody = json.decode(responseBody);

```
for (var data in jsonBody) {


  casaList.children.add(casa=data);
```

}
 //*********
If I try to put

casaList.children.add(casa..text=data['PersonName']);

it works but put in UListElement only the last element 'PersonName' from json (I have almost one hundred of persons that are retrieved from server with http.get).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps marshal the data into objects of the expected type?

```
for (var item in json.decode(responseBody)) {
    var li = new LIElement();
    li.text = item['PersonName']
    // [...]
    casaList.children.add(li)
}
```

Comment: I found a solution that works: for (int i = 0; i < jsonBody.length; i++) {
      LIElement ziua = LIElement();
      casaList.children.add(ziua..text=jsonBody[i]['Data']);}. I'll try anyway your solution also. Thank you!